# restricting the json parameters in REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am new to implement REST using Spring. I have created an REST API which accepts the `user` object for CRUD operation. The `user` entity has lot of fields mapped to the table like `created_time`, `updated_time` and some other field which I do not expect in the POST method. I just need the `username` and `age` in the object. How can I get this for both accepting and sending the response object as json.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping (value = "/user" , produces = {"application/json"}, consumes = {"application/json"})
public class UserController{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
        User user = userService.createUser(user);
        return user;
    }
```

Expected input `{username" :"Ram", age:: 33}` 
Expected response `{id;;24, username" :"Ram", age:: 33}`

Comment: super-easy way: create a model object of your user entity. Say, a "user resource" model with the attributes you need only.

Answer (score 1):

First, If you want to create a mature REST API then you'll have to mention a unique and meaningful URL, and add the appropriate HTTP Verb to it.

It would consider to be a better REST API handler if you'll write like this:

```
    @RestController
    public class UserController{

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user){
            HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
            header.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            User user = userService.createUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, header, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this case easily if you use Jackson for JSON de/serialization (just include it in your classpath). If Jackson doesn't find a field in JSON it will initialize the Java class field with the default value e.g. null. So when deserializing a `User` from the body of a POST request, it will set `username` and `age` and `id` will be 0 or null.

If you then want specific fields of `User` to be ignored only for serialization you may annotate the corresponding getter methods with `@JsonIgnore`.

If you want to ignore most fields and serialize only a few, then configure your `ObjectMapper mapper` like this:

```
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS);
```

and annotate specific fields with `@JsonProperty` e.g.

```
@JsonProperty
private static String username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate classes for seperate domains. If you only need user id, name and age for communicating via REST, have a `User` class in the REST package with only these properties. If you need a more complex object in other parts of your service have there another class representing a user.